# Author page get posts and pages of an author

Tags: wordpress, author

how is it possible to return the static pages as well as the posts of an author on it's archive page?
Our website uses the static pages for the informative content and the posts pages for the blog area.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: you can use WP_Query for querying the posts and can go through the documentation at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/ for reference

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can create a **author.php** page in your theme directory. Inside that page you can write simple WordPress loop and all your static content according to your needs .... In this way your author's posts will be showing up on this page ... for example you can go in this way .... let suppose we are writing this content inside **author.php** page;

```
<?php get_header();?>
 <?php 
    //all your static code and loop content will go here inside according to nature of content ...like static content with in DIVs and php content inside php tags etc
 ?>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Hope that make sense, for more info visit https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates